# Database connection issue

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

The following query is not executing and I am stumped as to why. The query is returning my `die` clause of 'error querying database' yet all of my info is exact.

Have I got a syntax error in my query variable?

```
<?php
$db_host     = 'localhost';
$db_user     = 'root';
$db_pass     = 'root';
$db_database = 'bbg_db_2'; 

$dbc = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die('Unable to establish a database connection');

$query = "SELECT category_name, category_desc FROM categories";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die ('error querying database');

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $catname = $row['category_name'];
    $catdesc = $row['category_desc'];

    echo "<li>$catname</br><span>$catdesc</span></li>";
}

mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

Comment: Post the output of `mysqli_error()` after the failed query. It should tell you exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: Why is your code halfway across my screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

- You connected with the `mysql` API, but then tried to query with the `mysqli` API;
- You never selected the database with `mysqli_select_db`.

Performing some basic error checking with `mysqli_error($dbc)` would have revealed this to you pretty quickly.

---

<sup>Also, as a style note, ARGH tabs *inside* lines! Bad! Wrong! Tabs are for indentation, not alignment.</sup>

Comment: Thankyou so much. I will stop with the tabs :o)

Comment: Sorry to bother you but I have implemented mysqli_error($dbc) which revealed that I hadn't selected the database and so I altered my code accordingly, however now I still do not get any results... no error message and nothing visible within my page. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Richard: My first bullet point, perhaps. Or maybe there are just no results.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I have amended the API to mysql which has not solved the problem. I can't see how there can be no results as I have a populated table in place. Im stuck. Probably some schoolboy error... I'll keep playing. Thanks anyway :o)

Comment: @Richard: At the risk of encouraging you to write a new question where you can't reproduce the issue for us to diagnose, perhaps give that a go anyway.

Comment: Done - The question can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776410/php-mysql-problem-displaying-query-results

Answer (score 4):

You have missed [mysql_select_db](http://bg.php.net/mysql_select_db)(`$db_database`) in your code.

Answer (score 4):

mysql_connect should be [mysqli_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php), cause you use mysqli_query after that and use [mysqli_select_db](http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/en/function.mysqli-select-db.php) to select database

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
... or die(mysqli_error());
```

instead, which will output the exact reason the query's failing.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up mysql and mysqli. You will need to pick one.